# char* (*vehicle)[][5]; dynamic allocation

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to dynamically allocate space for the following in C and I was wondering if someone could explain how to? char* (*vehicle)[][5];

The 5 elements are details of the vehicle and the first array is for the different vehicles. So I'm trying to dynamically allocate space for the different vehicles, numVehicles and each with 5 spots for string details. Doing the code below would allocate just the rows, but since the definition has 5 specified, do I need to multiple the number of vehicles in my allocation? Also, this data type is from the api, so I unfortunately can't change it and I'm not sure of the type vehicle, I was under the impression that the variable name.

Currently I'm doing:

```
char* (*vehicle)[][5];

vehicle = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numVehicles);
```

This appears to work in the code but I feel like I'm not doing the allocation correctly.

Comment: You should decide the language first. In C++, the onset itself is already wrong.

Comment: "vehicle" is declared as a pointer to an array without a specified size containing arrays of five pointers to chars. The malloc() is wrong, because it's allocating memory for five pointers to chars, instead of some specific number of arrays of five pointers to chars.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik: Strictly speaking, in the original `malloc` that "five" does come into the picture at all (which is a problem). The `malloc` is allocating memory for `numVehicles` pointers to `char`, not five pointers to `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your allocation is obviously incorrect, since it fails to take into account that `5` that you have in the array type your pointer points to. It might appear to work in the code if your code "compensates" for the allocation error by its own errors, e.g. by not using any additional memory that would have been provided by that `5`. We don't see your other code, which is why there's no way to say why it appeared to work.

Anyway, you can allocate it by

```
vehicle = malloc(numVehicles * sizeof **vehicle);
```

(`sizeof **vehicle` will give you `sizeof(char *[5])`).

Now you can access array elements as

```
(*vehicle)[vehicle_index][0] = "Ford Focus";
(*vehicle)[vehicle_index][1] = "ABS";
(*vehicle)[vehicle_index][2] = "Sunroof";
...
```

---

However, it is weird that you want to have `vehicle` as a pointer to an array of *unspecified* size, which is how your `vehicle` is declared. It will work, but it seems to be unnecessarily overcomplicated. If you have a choice, it would make more sense to declare `vehicle` as

```
char *(*vehicle)[5];
```

and allocate it as

```
vehicle = malloc(numVehicles * sizeof *vehicle);
```

In this case you will have too access it as

```
vehicle[vehicle_index][0] = "Ford Focus";
vehicle[vehicle_index][1] = "ABS";
vehicle[vehicle_index][2] = "Sunroof";
...
```

which is less convoluted than the previous example.

Comment: @Deduplicator: It is not possible to dereference it once in this case. `*vehicles` is unfortunately an incomplete type, to which `sizeof` cannot be applied. To make the `sizeof`-based code valid we have too sink deeper. This inelegance is caused by the fact that the OP wants to have a pointer to an array of unspecified size. Why? I have no idea.

Comment: @AndreyT: Should have looked a second time. +1

Answer (score 2):

Since this is pointer to a 2D array of `char *` pointers, where the minor dimension is 5, and the major dimension is dynamic and presumably equal to `numVehicles`, it should most likely be:

```
vehicle = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numVehicles * 5);
```